# I cant Upload photo in EasyAdmin3 Symfony4

Tags: mysql, image, symfony, symfony4, easyadmin3

I'm trying to upload photos in my easyadmin but i have many errors!the last one is:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image' in 'field list'

Here is my code:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
          return [
            TextField::new('nom'),
            TextField::new('code'),
            TextField::new('imageFile')->setFormType(VichImageType::class)->onlyWhenCreating(),
            ImageField::new('image')->setBasePath('/images/dossier')->onlyOnIndex(),
           ];
}
```

My Entity related to image:

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
* @var string
*/

```
private $image;

/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="dossier_images", fileNameProperty="image")
 * @var File
 */

private $imageFile;

service.yaml
parameters:
    dossier_images: /images/dossier
```

vich_uploader.yaml

```
mappings:
        dossier_images:
            uri_prefix: '%dossier_images%'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/%dossier_images%'
```

Comment: have you updated the db schema?

Comment: Oh my god no! :D thanks DonCallisto

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to run `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`